# Bower hangs on checkout?

Tags: bower

OK I'm trying use bower to install a package but to no avail

```
"bower install threejs"
```

Returns:

```
bower not-cached    git://github.com/mrdoob/three.js.git#*

bower resolve       git://github.com/mrdoob/three.js.git#*

bower checkout      threejs#master
```

and it hangs there.. why??

Comment: i'm having same problem. i've seen this everytime I use bower lately. I wonder if their servers are overloaded.

Comment: The repo is over 100MB. Could it be a slow connection?

Comment: @Tamlyn that's exactly what it was...